# Import part of a repository as lib

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

I am interested in creating an animation in Flutter using what this person has created: https://github.com/afgprogrammer/Flutter-Login-Page-UI/tree/master/lib/Animation. I am only interested in that particular class. Is there a way to import it to my flutter app as an external library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **Dart Package** with the code and then import this package to your app.

See here how to make a Dart Package : [Developing packages & plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#types)